# Как найти значение href по тексту внутри ссылки

Tags: php

Как с внешнего сайта можно получить значение href используя php.

```
    <a class="buy" href="site.ru/assort=61859" title="Поместить товар в корзину">
<b>купить: белый, S-M-L-XL-XXL</b></a>
```

Как получить значение href из ссылки если я знаю только значение из `<b>....</b>` ?

Comment: Jquery спасет вас

Comment: Мне нужно именно php так-как запрос проходит в бэкэнде.

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой вариант сработал.

```
$content = file_get_contents($url);
    $dom = new DomDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
    $finder = new DomXPath($dom);
    $anchors = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, 'buy')]");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$aa = '<a class="buy" href="site.ru/assort=61859" title="Поместить товар в корзину"><b>купить: белый, S-M-L-XL-XXL</b></a>'; 

preg_match("/href=\"(.*?)\"/", $aa, $matches); //поиск просто href
echo $matches[1];

preg_match("/href=\"(.*?)\".*?<b>купить: белый, S-M-L-XL-XXL<\/b>/", $aa, $matchesFull);    //поиск href где есть определенное значение <b>...</b>
echo $matchesFull[1];
```

Answer (score -1):

Отправить себе на бэкенд аякс запрос со значением.

Что-то типо

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'Ваш Урл',
  data: {href : $('.buy').attr('href')}
});
```

И уже дальше делать с ним нужные манипуляции.